# How to mark a directory as "not a project" in projectile?

Tags: projectile

I have a big version-controlled directory hosting a lot of half-independent bodies of work. I want to consider them all as projects for projectile.

So I added an empty `.projectile` file in each of them, with the idea that projectile would pick that up instead of the `.git` above.

So the situation is like this

```
~/main-directory/
 -> .git
 -> project1/
     -> .projectile
     -> file1
     -> file2
 -> project2/
     -> .projectile
     -> file1
     -> file2
```

But if I open `~/main-directory/project2/file1` and call `projectile-add-known-project`, it considers the whole `main-directory` as one project.  In particular, completion matches files with the same name in all subdirectories...

I have tried `(setq projectile-project-root-files-bottom-up (delete ".projectile" projectile-project-root-files-bottom-up))`, but it did not help.

Is there a simple way of telling projectile that the `main-directory` is not to be considered a project?

Answer (score 3):

The name is not explanatory, but the function `projectile-remove-current-project-from-known-projects` works fine: simply navigate to the `main-directory` and call the command. Visited subprojects will still appear in the project list.

More information: https://github.com/bbatsov/projectile/issues/315

One can also customize or set the variable `projectile-globally-ignored-directories` or `projectile-ignored-projects` to make the directory durably ignored. There must be a difference between the two, but I don't know it.

Comment: `projectile-globally-ignored-directories` is a list of regular expressions matching directories to be ignored within a project, such as .git and .svn (those are not in regexp form!).

 `projectile-ignored-projects` lists directories that should be excluded as projects entirely.